# Can there be applications of byzantine neural networks on quantum computers?

Tags: neural-networks, quantum-computing

This question came after I connected 2 pieces of information :

- I recently listened to [The Byzantine Generals’ Problem, Poisoning, and Distributed Machine Learning with El Mahdi El Mhamdi (Beneficial AGI 2019)](https://futureoflife.org/2019/01/30/ai-alignment-podcast-the-byzantine-problem-poisoning-and-distributed-machine-learning-with-el-mahdi-el-mhamdi-beneficial-agi-2019/?cn-reloaded=1).
- Today, I was laughing with a friend at "quantum computing" being mentioned in a job offer.

Considering the probabilistic nature of results in quantum computers, what would be the advantages to using byzantine resistant neural networks on quantum computer? Has this already been attempted?